# Bookdown: Citations at end of sections in single HTML output file

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am looking to get the citations I use at the end of sections (i.e. 2.1.). To accomplish this, the output format can be set as:

```
output: 
    bookdown::gitbook:
        split_by: section
```

This works fine, but I want to render the file into a single HTML file for use of sharing with colleagues. The only way I can get that to work is through the code:

```
output: 
    bookdown::gitbook:
        split_by: none
```

Which obviously puts all citations at the very end of the file. Is there any way to get the citations at the end of the sections, yet render a single HTML file?

Comment: bookdown does not support sectioned bibliography for a single HTML output page.

Comment: I figured, but was hoping there was hack to get it done. Thanks!

Comment: bookdown is essentially a bag of hacks. It is not impossible to implement, but I just don't have time for it...